# Application specific screen recorder for Android

Tags: video-recording, video-capture, obs, android

For windows, using OBS studio, I can record the screen of a particular application. If in between, I open another window, the recorder records only the selected window and not the window on top.

But on android, all the screen recorder apps I've seen record what's shown on the screen. In between, if some notification pops up, that is also recorded. I want to avoid that for privacy concerns. Is there any app which does that? I don't mind if it shows blank screen when some other app or notification pops up.